# Outputting database data to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've been trying to follow the information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple) and and the code [here](http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableFromDatabase.java) and I'm having some difficulty.

The database query works and I've outputted it successfully to console. Following the above guides I've since added some code that puts the ResultSet data into the required Vectors. This is my code:

```
public class Reports extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField dateFromYYYY;
    private JTextField dateFromMM;
    private JTextField dateFromDD;
    private JTextField dateToYYYY;
    private JTextField dateToMM;
    private JTextField dateToDD;

    private JTextField ownerNameInput;
    private JTextField petNameInput;
    private JTextField doctorNameInput;

    private JCheckBox isPaid = new JCheckBox("Is Paid");

    public static JTable table;
    public static boolean printTable = true;
    private String printHeader;

    // Static Variables

    private final static String BOOKINGS_TABLES = "FROM Doctor, Pet, Treatment, Visit ";

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    private void SearchFrame() {
        setTitle("Generate a Report");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 981, 551);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblWhatWouldYou = new JLabel("What would you like a report for?");
        lblWhatWouldYou.setBounds(36, 10, 200, 50);
        contentPane.add(lblWhatWouldYou);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(260, 60, 690, 370);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }


    private void DateFields(){
        // From Date
        //Year
        JLabel lblFromDate = new JLabel("From          dd:");
        lblFromDate.setBounds(20, 180, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblFromDate);

        JLabel lblFromYear = new JLabel("yyyy:");
        lblFromYear.setBounds(180, 180, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblFromYear);
        dateFromYYYY = new JTextField();
        dateFromYYYY.setBounds(210, 180, 40, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateFromYYYY);

        //Month
        JLabel lblFromMonth = new JLabel("mm:");
        lblFromMonth.setBounds(128, 180, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblFromMonth);
        dateFromMM = new JTextField();
        dateFromMM.setBounds(155, 180, 20, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateFromMM);

        dateFromDD = new JTextField();
        dateFromDD.setBounds(100, 180, 20, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateFromDD);

        // To Date
        //Year
        JLabel lblToDate = new JLabel("To               dd:");
        lblToDate.setBounds(20, 210, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblToDate);

        JLabel lblToYear = new JLabel("yyyy:");
        lblToYear.setBounds(180, 210, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblToYear);
        dateToYYYY = new JTextField();
        dateToYYYY.setBounds(210, 210, 40, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateToYYYY);

        //Month
        JLabel lblToMonth = new JLabel("mm:");
        lblToMonth.setBounds(128, 210, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblToMonth);
        dateToMM = new JTextField();
        dateToMM.setBounds(155, 210, 20, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateToMM);

        dateToDD = new JTextField();
        dateToDD.setBounds(100, 210, 20, 25);
        contentPane.add(dateToDD);

    }

    private void PetName(){
        JLabel lblPetName = new JLabel("Pet Name:");
        lblPetName.setBounds(20, 90, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblPetName);

        petNameInput = new JTextField();
        petNameInput.setBounds(100, 90, 150, 25);
        contentPane.add(petNameInput);
    }

    private void OwnerName(){
        JLabel lblOwnerName = new JLabel("Owner Name:");
        lblOwnerName.setBounds(20, 120, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblOwnerName);

        ownerNameInput = new JTextField();
        ownerNameInput.setBounds(100, 120, 150, 25);
        contentPane.add(ownerNameInput);
    }

    private void DoctorName(){
        JLabel lblDoctorName = new JLabel("Doctor Name:");
        lblDoctorName.setBounds(20, 150, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(lblDoctorName);

        doctorNameInput = new JTextField();
        doctorNameInput.setBounds(100, 150, 150, 25);
        contentPane.add(doctorNameInput);
    }

    private void IsPaidCheckBox(){
        isPaid.setBounds(155, 250, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(isPaid);
    }

    public void Bookings() {
        // Local variables
        Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
        Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

        // Instantiate the frame
        SearchFrame();
        // Set search fields
        PetName();
        OwnerName();
        DoctorName();
        IsPaidCheckBox();
        DateFields();

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String queryString00 = "";
                String queryString01 = "SELECT pet.petname AS [Pet Name], pet.ownerName AS [Owner Name], doctor.doctorName AS [Doctor Name], visit.visitDate AS [Visit Date], treatment.treatmentName AS [Treatment Name], visit.ispaid AS [Is Paid] ";
                String queryString03 = "WHERE Visit.petID = Pet.petID ";
                String queryString02 = " GROUP BY visitID;";

                // build the query
                if(!(petNameInput.getText().equals("")))
                    queryString00 =  queryString01 + BOOKINGS_TABLES + queryString03 + "AND petname LIKE " + "'%" + petNameInput.getText() + "%'";
                else queryString00 =  queryString01 + BOOKINGS_TABLES + queryString03;

                if(!(ownerNameInput.getText().equals("")))
                    queryString00 = queryString00 + "AND ownername LIKE " + "'%" + ownerNameInput.getText() + "%'";

                if(!(doctorNameInput.getText().equals("")))
                    queryString00 = queryString00 + "AND doctorname LIKE " + "'%" + doctorNameInput.getText() + "%'";


                if(!(dateFromYYYY.getText().equals(""))){
                    String fromString = dateFromYYYY.getText() + "-" + dateFromMM.getText() + "-" + dateFromDD.getText();
                    queryString00 = queryString00 + " AND visitdate >= '" + fromString + "'";
                }

                if(!(dateToYYYY.getText().equals(""))){
                    String toString = dateToYYYY.getText() + "-" + dateToMM.getText() + "-" + dateToDD.getText();
                    queryString00 = queryString00 + " AND visitdate <= '" + toString + "'";
                }

                if(isPaid.isSelected())
                    queryString00 = queryString00 + " AND ispaid = 'Y'";

                queryString00 = queryString00 + queryString02;
//              System.out.println(queryString00);

                DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                db.openConn();

                // Get query
                ResultSet rs = db.getSearch(queryString00);
                ResultSetMetaData md = null;

                // Set up vectors for table output
                // Output query to screen (Much of the following code is adapted from http://www.camick.com/java/source/TableFromDatabase.java)
                try{
                    md = rs.getMetaData();
                    int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
                    // Get column names
                    for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                        columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));

                    while(rs.next()){
//                      System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", rs.getString("Pet Name"), rs.getString("Owner Name"), rs.getString("Doctor Name"), rs.getString("Visit Date"), rs.getString("Treatment Name"), rs.getString("Is Paid"));
                        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columnCount);
                        for(int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
                            row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
                        data.addElement(row);
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                db.closeConn();
                }

        //  Create table with database data
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
            {
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public Class getColumnClass(int column)
                {
                    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                    {
                        Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                        if (o != null)
                        {
                            return o.getClass();
                        }
                    }

                    return Object.class;
                }
            };

            // Out put to the table (theoretically)
            JTable table = new JTable(columnNames, data);
            this.scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
//          JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
//          getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        });
        btnSearch.setBounds(36, 460, 165, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnSearch);

        JLabel resultLabel = new JLabel("Reports will be printed below");
        resultLabel.setBounds(515, 10, 312, 50);
        contentPane.add(resultLabel);

        JButton printReport = new JButton("Print Report");
        printReport.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String resultLabelPrint = resultLabel.getText();
                    MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat(resultLabelPrint);
                    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat(printHeader);
                    boolean complete =table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header , footer );
                    if (complete) {
                        /* show a success message  */

                    } else {
                        /*show a message indicating that printing was cancelled */

                    }
                } catch (PrinterException pe) {
                    /* Printing failed, report to the user */

                }
            }
        });
        printReport.setBounds(473, 460, 227, 25);
        contentPane.add(printReport);

    }

}
```

The final part of the code, which I believe out puts to the table, gives me some weird errors.

```
            // Out put to the table (theoretically)
            JTable table = new JTable(columnNames, data);
            this.scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
//          JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
//          getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
```

The first line gives me a syntax error on the semi-colon (;), specifically, Syntax error on token ";", invalid AssignmentOperator. I get the same when I try the 'model' variable.

When I uncomment the last two lines I get 'Syntax error on token ".", { expected' and the Eclipse demands another closing { despite there not being a corresponding opening }. If I add it then I get more errors.

I suspect this has something to do with the class structure of the code that I'm trying to follow but I'm having no luck in following those either.

All I want to do is to take the information that I have and output it in the table which is already there. How do I do this?

Comment: `scrollPane` is not a global instance.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Don't re-create the `JTable` or `JScrollPane`.  Create these and add them to your UI, create a instance field of `JTable` so you can reference from within your class.  Query the database and add the new data to a new `TableModel`, once you have this done, apply the table model to the instance of `JTable`...

Comment: Take a closer look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).  You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: "Query the database and add the new data to a new TableModel, once you have this done, apply the table model to the instance of JTable.."       And how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`scrollPane` is not a global instance.

Move `JScrollPane scrollPane` out of your method `SearchFrame()` and place it into your list of instance variables for the class.

That is only your immediate and first issue, your other issue is that your are attempting to access instance variables defined in `Reports` within the scope of 2x nested anonymous classes.

You should parametarize your GUI methods to accept the components for injection into the panels.

```
public class Reports extends JFrame {
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    ...

    private void SearchFrame() {
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane ();
    }
    ...

    public void Bookings() {
        scrollPane...
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Better yet, make `JTable` the instance field, add it to an instance of the `JScrollPane`, add the `JScrollPane` to the frame and then simply change the tables model as needed

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing all the error messages nor the **complete** error messages (please fix this). The most important one is the, `Cannot refer to the non-final local variable data defined in an enclosing scope` message. So make the variables final -- one problem solved.

```
public void Bookings() {
    // Local variables
    final Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>(); //!! made final
    final Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();
```

The other problem is that this code:

```
       JTable table = new JTable(columnNames, data);
       this.scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

Is being called outside of any and all methods. You need to match up your curly braces carefully.

Question that confuses me about your code though -- why create a TableModel and not use it as a model for your JTable?

Comment: "why create a TableModel and not use it as a model for your JTable?"    -  That was me playing about seeing if I could get it to work. Have reset the code to use the table model created.